# Show uniform convergence of a series involving ln function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x}{n} \ln(1 + \frac{x}{n})\right) }$ converges uniformly on $(-1, A)$ for  $A > -1$ and that the sum of the series has derivatives of all orders on $(-1,\infty)$.

Attempt: (a) I cannot bound the series. I did  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\ln(n+x)-\ln(n))^{\frac{x}{n}}$. Then what next?

Comment: You approach doesn't look promising, since you get a more complicated-looking expression than you started with.  I suggest you try to bound $\ln(1+x/n)$ separately, to begin with.$

Comment: I still cannot bound. I wonder if its something to do with $e^x$ and limit of $ln(1+ (x/n))$

Comment: Have you tried using the power series for $\ln(1+x)?$  I don't know if this works, it's just the first thing I'd try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$. In particular, there is an interval $[-a,a]$, $0<a<1$, such that $|\ln(1+x)|\le2\,|x|$ if $x\in[-a,a]$.